# Using NTPD as a client on Cent OS without Undisciplined Local Clock any disadvantage?

Tags: linux, centos, clock, virtual-machine, ntp

The following is the NTP configuration. 
My server is a physical system, not a virtual machine.
The following ntp-4.2.2p1-15.el5.centos rpm I am using.

```
tinker panic 0
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
server 0.pool.ntp.org
#server  127.127.1.0     # local clock
#fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

The intention of this configuration is to have a common /etc/ntp.conf for my physical machine and for Virtual Machine.

My server act as a NTP client not as a NTP server. Is there any disadvantage for not using the undisciplined Local Clock on physical machine?

Comment: Let me simplify my question: Is it must to have a local clock as a server in the ntp.conf when we are acting as a NTP client? what is the disadvantage if we don't configure the local clock config?

Comment: You should have more than one server.